# How to import my main file and Create database connection?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to import my database connection file into another file and create a connection in that file?  For example, I have a main file in the name **"Database_main.py"**In my main file I have a function like. **establish_connection, change _passkey** . Now I have to import the main file(Database_main.py) things in my second file(database_connection.py). But I got a error message  **"TypeError: establish_connection_general() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**. How to sucessfully import my main file and make a connection.
**Database_main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QMessageBox,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

import sqleet
import os
import sys

file_path_general = r"d:\project database\assist"
db_name_general = (os.path.join(file_path_general,'database_general.db'))

passkey_general = "1234"
new_passkey_general = "1234"

show_errormsg = "show"


class Database_connection(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__()
        self.establish_connection_general()
        # self.cahnge_passkey()

    def establish_connection_general(self):
        try:
            connection_general = sqleet.connect(db_name_general,key = passkey_general)
            print("open scueffully")
        except Exception as e:
            if show_errormsg == "show":
                self.handle_error(e)
            else:
                pass


    def cahnge_passkey(self):
        try:
            general_connection = sqleet.connect(db_name_general,key = passkey_general)
            general_connection.change_key(new_passkey_general)
            print("new pass key sucessfully changed")
            general_connection.close()

        except Exception as e:
            if show_errormsg == "show":
                self.handle_error(e)
            else:
                pass

    def handle_error(self,error):
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        filenamewithpath = exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
        head,tail = os.path.split((filenamewithpath))
        lineno = exc_traceback.tb_lineno
        name = exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_name
        type = exc_type.__name__
        message = exc_value
        nl = '\n'
        kk = f'File Name : {tail[:-3]}{nl}'\
             f'Line No. : {lineno}{nl}'\
             f'Type : {type}{nl}'\
             f'Name : {name}{nl}'
        self.msg = QMessageBox()
        self.msg.setFixedSize(1600,400)
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("  Error/Bugs Information")
        self.msg.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon\close006.png'))
        fd = "                                                                           "
        self.msg.setText(f'{type} - {lineno}{fd}')
        self.msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.msg.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.msg.setInformativeText("")
        self.msg.setDetailedText(kk)
        self.msg.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Database_connection()
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Database_Connection file**

```
import sys
import os

from makeeasy_database_connection import Database_connection

db = Database_connection.establish_connection_general()
db()
```

**Result**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/project database/assist/database_connection.py", line 6, in <module>
    db = Database_connection.establish_connection_general()
TypeError: establish_connection_general() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How to import properly and use my code ?

Comment: You do it like you did in the main code -- you create an instance of the class.  `db = Database_connection()` / `db.establish_connection_general()`.

Comment: It also not work for me @ TimeRoberts

Comment: it looks like you call `establish_connection_general` in the constructor anyway...

Comment: You need to separate the database connection from the QWidget.  You don't want to create QWidgets in all of your other files.

Comment: The database class should be a plain `object`, which does not use any PyQt classes at all. It should raise custom exceptions which can then be handled elsewhere by the caller. The error handler should be centralised in another module (possibly also using an [exect-hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook)). If you do things that way, you can create a singleton instance of `Database_connection` as a module-global variable which can be directly imported by other modules. But don't call `establish_connection_general` in `__init__` - let the calling code do that instead.